# colocar imagen en posición concreta en función de las coordenadas del ratón

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Estoy tratando de generar una cuadricula con python y pygame para que las imágenes se dibujen en unas coordenadas concretas en función de las coordenadas del ratón

La idea es que si picamos en cualquier parte del recuadro el origen de coordenadas de la imagen, sea su esquina superior izquierda.

Adjunto una imagen con la idea

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la forma más sencilla que he encontrado, pero requeriría que para cada cuadro generase una línea y en caso de ser una rejilla grande, de 10x10 debería generar 100 líneas para tener en cuenta todas las posiciones.

```
    elif evento.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        x = pos[0]
        y = pos[1]

        if (0 <= pos[0] <= 100) and (0 <= pos[1] <= 100): x, y = 0, 0
        elif (101 <= pos[0] <= 200) and (0 <= pos[1] <= 100): x, y = , 100

        pantalla.blit(copiaImagen,(x,y))
```

Habría alguna forma de hacer esto mediante un bucle o una lista?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que quieres es "redondear" cualquier entero al múltiplo de 100 más cercano por debajo ¿no es eso?

La siguiente función haría lo que necesitas:

```
def ajustar(numero, paso=100):
     return numero//paso * paso
```

El "paso" (tamaño de la rejilla) es opcional y le puse por defecto el valor 100.

En python3 el operador `//` hace la división entera, es decir, se queda con el cociente y no saca decimales. Si a esa parte entera la multiplicas por el paso, ya tienes lo que buscabas.

Así pues, en tu código:

```
x = ajustar(pos[0])
y = ajustar(pos[1])
```

O incluso, si te gusta la programación funcional:

```
x, y = map(ajustar, pos)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, en cuanto tenga un momento lo pruebo, tenía funcionando algo similar con el operador // pero no había pensado en usarlo asi

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias, esto funcionó exactamente como quería.

Comment: @Rob De nada. Sobre como funciona este sitio, puedes leer [qué hacer cuando alguien responde mi pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [el recorrido general](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)